# Using AJAX to Load Full Pages?

Tags: javascript, ajax

An example of what I'm trying to do can be seen here:http://www.codeandtheory.com/#/about/

When any other link is clicked, it smoothly loads the next page.  I have read that using /#!/ is better than /#/ so How would I add /#!/ to my website so I can use ajax to load my pages?

Is there any fallback in case a site visitor does not have javascript enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers support [HTML5 pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to update the url. What you are talking about is [Google's hash Bang](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html).

Answer (score 0):

Fallback is to set the links normally from the backend template, and then rewrite them with # in JavaScript if it is enabled. That way links still are usable for non JS/crawlers.

You need to setup your paths so that they are usable with or without JS:

```
/#/about
/about
```

Link to same place. So if the link has been rewritten to the # format, it won't trigger a refresh, but instead trigger a JS AJAX load of that location.